# Access list of functions and metadata for github dev R package

Tags: r, function, devtools

**Please Note:** This is cross-posted from [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/access-list-of-functions-and-metadata-for-github-dev-r-package/99157) where it hasn't received a response.
So I'm adding it here.

I'm currently co-developing an `R` package on github which can be installed using `devtools::install_github('repo/pkgname)`, as usual.

We have diligently used  `roxygen2` to document the individual functions.
We have split the functions into "internal" (`@keywords internal`) vs. "external" (`@export`)
so that the user gets to use the external functions i.e.`pkgname::external_<fn_name>`
and access documentation. They can also use `:::` to access the internal
functions if they wish.

For some meta analysis of our package it would be nice to have a functionality
that produced a tidy tibble with the following columns:

- function name,
- function type i.e. internal/external (accessible by `::` or `:::` to the user)
- More metadata e.g. another column containing parameter names for each function i.e. `@param` values
- documentation strings for each parameter

As a crude version (non-tibble format) for say dplyr. One can do something like:

```
library(dplyr) # Assume installed already
ls('package:dplyr')
```

This produces a character vector of function names, but not a tidy tibble with more
useful metadata.

Ideally we would be able to produce this tibble after doing `devtools::load_all(".")` in
our package development, to track changes in real-time.

Are there any existing `R`  packages that can help generate such a metadata `tibble`?
Or can such a function be developed for this using existing `R` packages?

Would appreciate any help associated with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer to my question, which may help others. It turns out this metadata can be accessed using the amazing `pkgdown` package.

See below for code to use when you have opened an RStudio project attached to a package
you are developing (using `devtools`):

```
# Setup - install required libraries
# install.packages(c("pkgdown", "here"))

# If you are in your local package directory, run the following
# to get the required package metadata
pkg <- pkgdown::as_pkgdown(pkg = here::here())

# Inspect the topics object, which contains function metadata
pkg$topics %>% dplyr::glimpse()

# Get list of all functions and just required metadata
pkg_fns_all <- pkg$topics %>%
    dplyr::select(name, file_in, internal)

# Get the non-internal functions, acccessed using pkgname::function
pkg_fns_user <- pkg_fns_all %>% dplyr::filter(!internal)

# Get the internal functions, acccessed using pkgname:::function
pkg_fns_internal <- pkg_fns_all %>% dplyr::filter(internal)
```

Hope this helps others :slight_smile:

A few small outstanding items:

- I'm not sure how to get access to individual function `@param` values from the
  above, but if anyone can add some details around that it would be useful.
- I'm not sure how to apply this to `CRAN` installed packages on my system e.g. `dplyr`